# is my .htaccess if okay? i am unable to use directores in main domain

Tags: .htaccess, slash, trailing

I have used following .htaccess file

```
#remove .php from url
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]


#force https on all urls
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#redirect all www to no-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#disable directly listing and browsing
Options -Indexes

# Force trailing slash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, i want to access this URL: mydomain.com/products/myproduct.php

**its working well but not removing .php from url and not adding trailing slash in it.**

any solution?

i try many solution found on stackoverflow but not fix it yet

Comment: Did i add trailing slash code twice? once in remove .php from url and onces at the end?

Comment: Yes, you did. And the rest is also not in a good order - any external redirects to force HTTPS and fix the host name, should come first, other stuff after that.